# django-crispy-forms are not working as expected

Tags: forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

My django-crispy-forms are not working.

**Following code is my html template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}NewsLetter | {%endblock head_title%}

{% block content%} 
    <h1> {{title}} </h1>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">          
    <form  method = 'POST' action = ''> {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form | crispy }}
    <input  class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value="Subscribe" />
    </form>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Here is to see how it looks

[image]

Comment: What is there supposed to be? Looks ok to me. Input field and a Button. What else do you need?

Comment: it is not responsive ,